# How elements in array are obtained by index?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I am learning about array as a data structure and I'm interested in how exactly in Java we obtain an element in an array by index.

What's happening under the hood when the following code is executed:

```
...
int i = array[2];
```

How JVM stores refferences to primitive types in array? How we obtain the element in O(1)? Does JVM calculates position of the element relative other element?

Comment: You can get some idea from https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=201706071240291279792

Comment: array[2] just points to a specific location in memory. if we know where the value is located, then there is no search required thus O(1) is achieved, of course how memory is handled internally, is a different story but that is and related to java

Comment: For objects, there's a sequential array of pointers to the actual elements stored in memory. When you reference `array`, Java looks at that array. When you say `array[2]`, Java reads the applicable pointer from the array to find the corresponding element. For primitives, there's a sequential array of the actual items stored in memory. I'd post an answer, but I don't feel like drawing a picture to explain it properly right now.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays like int[], double[], etc. Is native arrays.
The Reference to native array is the reference to its first element.
Element with index "i" will be getted by dereferencing ("reference on the first element" + i * sizeOf("contained type")).

P.s. In the Java they are wrapped in other class for checking bounds, getting length and so on. In the low-level programming languages like C++ you can broke your programm, when u will try to change element by index grater than array length